Issue with Commit Upload for Win32 App in Intune via PowerShell Runbook
I'm encountering an issue while trying to upload a Win32 app to Intune. The app is an .exe installer that I converted to an IntuneWin file before attempting the upload using a PowerShell runbook. Everything goes well until I try to invoke the commit. At that point, I consistently receive an error from the API, stating that the commit file upload failed.
I'm also uncertain about the encryption parameters for the upload file and how to correctly set them, which might be contributing to the issue. I haven't found sufficient documentation to resolve this.
Has anyone successfully navigated this, or could offer advice on the correct encryption parameters and other troubleshooting steps? Your help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for any help!
Thomas
Here is the relevant script part that errors out:
# Upload the .intunewin file
Write-Output "Uploading the .intunewin file to Azure Storage Blob..."
$UploadHeaders = @{ "x-ms-blob-type" = "BlockBlob" }

try {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $UploadUrl -Method PUT -InFile $LocalIntunewinPath -Headers $UploadHeaders
    Write-Output "Fileupload initiated successfully."
}
catch {
    Write-Error "File upload failed: $_"
    exit 1
}

# Compute the file hash for fileDigest
try {
    $fileHash = Get-FileHash -Path $InstallerPath -Algorithm "SHA256"
    $fileDigest = $fileHash.Hash
    Write-Output "File hash computed successfully."
    Write-Output "File digest: $fileDigest"
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to compute the file hash. $_"
    exit 1
}

$params = @{
    fileEncryptionInfo = @{
        encryptionKey = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("ZW5jcnlwdGlarastpasdfghvbktleQ==")
        initializationVector = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("mCUJiXgpsIh6Iw==")
        mac = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("qd6ib2MB6vhV0wluUWhRrua2VlSpr5w=")
        macKey = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("YuHdplSXFnMQs7UaJOyg3UQKjEkgjW+=")
        profileIdentifier = "ProfileVersion1"
        fileDigest = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($fileDigest)
        fileDigestAlgorithm = "SHA256"
    }
}

try {
    Invoke-MgBetaCommitDeviceAppManagementMobileAppMicrosoftGraphWin32LobAppContentVersionFile -MobileAppId $AppId -MobileAppContentId $ContentVersionId -MobileAppContentFileId $FileId -BodyParameter $params
    Write-Output "Filecommit started successfully."
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to commit the uploaded file. $_"
    exit 1
}

# Wait for the file to be processed
Write-Output "Polling the uploadState until it becomes 'commitFileSuccess'..."
$retryCount = 0
$maxRetries = 60
do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    $FileStatusURI = "$GraphBaseURI/mobileApps/$AppId/microsoft.graph.win32LobApp/contentVersions/$ContentVersionId/files/$FileId"
    $FileStatusResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $FileStatusURI -Headers $Global:AuthenticationHeader -Method GET
    $UploadState = $FileStatusResponse.uploadState
    Write-Output "Current upload state: $UploadState"
    if ($UploadState -eq "commitFileFailed") {
        Write-Error "File processing failed. Please check the log for more details."
        exit 1
    }
    $retryCount++
    if ($retryCount -ge $maxRetries) {
        Write-Error "File processing did not complete within the expected time."
        exit 1
    }
} while ($UploadState -ne "commitFileSuccess")

